# which type of diversity is used by rake receivers?

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, multipath, diversity

My question is:

Which type of diversity technique is used by the rake receivers?

In Bahai, et. al. "*Multi-Carrier Digital Communications Theory and Applications of OFDM,*"
Second Edition, 2004, on page 27, it is said that RAKE, OFDM, and Equalization, are all using frequency diversity, but here and there on the internet and papers I see it is said that rake is using time diversity!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received this email from one of the greatest in wireless communications: Dr. Fuyun Ling.
He said:
"I think the confusion point is what is the definition of the (optimal) frequency or time diversity.  I don't think there is such a rigorous definition.  If we define the optimal frequency/time diversities as a receiver combining the signal components containing in all available frequencies/time paths, then an optimal receiver must achieve (optimal) frequency diversity.  At the same time, it also achieves (optimal) time diversity.  An ideal rake receiver is a matched filter.  Thus, it is an optimal receiver.  We can think it achieves (optimal) time diversity as well as (optimal) frequency diversity."

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it's more natural to describe the RAKE receiver as a time-diversity system.

However, in a wireless system multipath is only resolvable if the bandwidth is large, so RAKE receivers are only useful for wideband signals. So, in a sense, the RAKE receiver depends on the fact that the channel exhibits frequency-selectivity, which can also be described as a form of frequency diversity.

Comment: I aggree wth @MBaz, because RAKE receiver combines the multipath components received from different time instants.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the rake receiver scheme that I'm familiar with, it's a spread-spectrum signal using a pseudo-random code, and finding multiple correlation peaks in the received signal (which, if you plot it out as delay vs. signal strength looks like a rake -- it took me a long time to figure out that it's not an acronym; it's a metaphor).

So to the extent that one can firmly bin it into either time- or frequency-diversity, I'd put it into time-diversity.